# HTML Scaling issue to fit content

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm fairly new to web-development, and at the moment I'm learning responsive design. I'm have some difficulty with making my websites content fix properly on small screens like smart phones.
Tried using media queries but am fairly new on the subject so any help would be apricated.

GitHub: https://github.com/JackDef10/Web-portfolio.git
Website: https://jackdef10.github.io/Web-portfolio/

Comment: just add ```<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />``` inside your head tag!

Comment: Why are you linking ```main.css``` when it is not present inside your Resource folder. Your entire ```HTML``` structure is wrong

Comment: @KunalTanwar I added the meta tag but the content is still all over the place when I inspect it in google and change the device view to mobile. I admit my html structure is not great, thinking of just re-doing the whole thing any advice on how I could improve it would be apricated. Thank you